# Angular 2 seed - how to enable compass support in sass file

Tags: gulp, compass, angular-seed, gulp-compass

I use [this](https://github.com/archfirst/angular2-seed-sass/issues/9) seed project for my Angular 2 app.

My goal is to use compass mixins and functions in all sass files.

In this moment when i try to use @import 'compass' it simply can not make import.

I had instaled newest SASS and COMPASS gem.

I think to do this i need some config.rb but i have no idea how to properly place it in this files structure.

Or maybe i need [gulp-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass) and implement some gulp's task to enable compass, when whole app build-up?

But when exactly start this task and how should code for this task look like ?

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular at all

Comment: It is becouse it is used inside angular 2 seed project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use compass mixin only, it is better to use [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins). It contains most compass mixins as 'original Compass' provided.

Here are the steps:

1. npm install --save-dev compass-mixins
2. Edit SASS options in [seed.config.ts](https://github.com/archfirst/angular2-seed-sass/blob/master/tools/config/seed.config.ts)

   `SASS_OPTIONS: SassOptions = {
       includePaths: ['./node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/']
   };`

Then it should work in [angular2-seed-sass](https://github.com/archfirst/angular2-seed-sass). Because I did similar thing in [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) and it works.

After play with [gulp-compass](https://github.com/appleboy/gulp-compass), [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) for 2 days, I believe that the above solution should be the simplest.